# CountDownTimer that responds to clicks

Tags: java, android, timer

**The app:** Creates CountDownTimers and displays them in a simple layout. The user can choose how long the timer should be through SharedPreferences and a settings activity. Each timer has a preparation period before it actually starts.

**The problem:** I'm not sure how, but I feel like the code is messy and needs to be cleaned up. In particular, the CountDownTimer is nested five layers deep:

```
public void startSession(View v) {
    if (!isTicking) {
        // Runs on play press
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(session.getPrepRemaining() + session.getMindRemaining(), 10) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (millisUntilFinished > session.getMindRemaining()) {
                    // Preparation timer
                    session.setPrepRemaining(millisUntilFinished - session.getMindRemaining());
                    setPrepDigits(millisUntilFinished - session.getMindRemaining());
                } else {
                    // Mindfulness timer
                    prepDigits.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    session.setMindRemaining(millisUntilFinished);
                    circularProgressBar.setProgress(((session.getMindLength() - millisUntilFinished) / (float) session.getMindLength()) * 100);
                    setMindDigits(millisUntilFinished);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                session = null;
                isTicking = false;
                circularProgressBar.setProgress(100);
                initializeSession();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
        isTicking = true;
        startPauseButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause));

        // Alarm
        AlarmReceiver.scheduleAlarm(this);
    } else {
        // Runs on pause press
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        isTicking = false;
        startPauseButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));
    }
}
```

If you'd like to see the rest of the code, please check out the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6713261222647889ef74db8e876be8ee).

It seems like I should have one class managing the counting and another class managing UI, but again, I'm just not sure what steps I should take to make that happen. I also feel like there are several blocks of code that could be pulled out into their own methods, but I feel like they'd be too entwined with, for example, the timer itself.

I've been doing a lot of reading on clean code, and I'm aware of the principles, but I don't know how to put them into practice. So, **how can I organize, simplify, and clarify my code?**

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to separate the `CountDownTimer` class logic instead of anonymous implementation.  I just made the below sample code which I try to loose coupled the `CountDownTimer` from the `Activity`

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    TextView textViewTime;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        textViewTime.setText("00:03:00");
        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000, 1000);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTime.setText("Completed.");
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }
    }
}
```